# Random generation of wealth with normal distribution of two parameters?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, random-effects-model, joint-distribution

I want to randomly generate the wealth of a group of people, with two parameters: age and height.

Basically (not necessarily realistic):

Rule 1. the older a person (allow decimals), the higher the wealth.

Rule 2. the larger the height, the lower the wealth.

Let's say I am given the data of age and height of 100 people, and rule 1 and rule 2 are equally importantm, i.e. the weights of age and height as the parameters are the same.

With $r1$ being a random number from 1 to 100, 
and $r2$ being a random number from 1 to 100.

One random generation of wealth, wealth = $e^{r1\cdot\text{height} + r2\cdot\text{age}} + 50$, with height and age unitless.

But this is not normal distribution. As the comment point out, I hope to generate something like $N(\text{wealth}|a⋅\text{age}−b⋅\text{height},\sigma_2)$. How can I generate wealth using normal distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) instead. If $X$ is log-normal, then $Y=\ln(X)$ is normal.

You can then sample wealth values via:
$$ w \sim \text{lognormal}(\alpha A - \beta H,\sigma(A,H)^2) $$
where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}_+$, $A$ is age, and $H$ is height.